# How to find out why my program keeps having an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code, I'm trying to end the loop once the answers is equals to 0 but it keeps going on an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int x, remainder;
    cout << "please enter a positive integer number: " << endl;
    string tab;
    tab = '\t';
    cin >> x;
    remainder = x % 2;

    do{
        while ( x % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << x << " is odd" << tab << "Subtract 1" << tab << " Half of " << x - 1 << " is " << x / 2;
            x = (x - 1) / 2;
            cout  << endl;

        }

        while (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << x << " is even" << tab << "Subtract 0" << tab << "Half of  " << x << " is " << x / 2;
            x = x / 2;
            cout << endl;
        }

    }
    while (x >= 0);  
}
```

Comment: What do you think happens to your second loop when `x` is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, essentially, two problems in your code, both of which, in themselves, will make your loop run endlessly.

Starting from the outside and working inwards: The test at the end of your (outer) `while` loop will always be "true", as you have `while (x >= 0)`; so, even when x gets to zero (as it will), the loop will keep running! (And, once x is zero it will remain zero!)

Second, the two 'inner' while loops shouldn't be loops at all! You want one or the other 'block' to run ***once only*** for each main loop - so use an `if ... else` structure.

The following is a corrected version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
//  using namespace std; // Generally, not good practice (and frowned-upon here on SO)
    using std::cin;  using std::cout; using std::endl; // Use only those you want to!
    using std::string;
    int x, remainder;
    cout << "please enter a positive integer number: " << endl;
    string tab;
    tab = '\t';
    cin >> x;
    remainder = x % 2;

    do {
        if (x % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << x << " is odd" << tab << "Subtract 1" << tab << " Half of " << x - 1 << " is " << x / 2;
            x = (x - 1) / 2;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else // if (x % 2 == 0) ... but we don't need to test this again.
        {
            cout << x << " is even" << tab << "Subtract 0" << tab << "Half of  " << x << " is " << x / 2;
            x = x / 2;
            cout << endl;
        }
    } while (x > 0); // You run forever if you have x >= 0!
    return 0;
}
```

*There are a few other things that could be changed to make the code more "efficient," but I'll let you peruse the MNC (Minimum Necessary Change) before we start editing towards a BPC (Best Possible Code)!*

EDIT: OK, due to 'peer pressure' from comments , I'll put in a ***suggested*** BPC now:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::cin;  using std::cout; using std::endl; // Use only those you want to!
    int x;// , remainder; // "remainder" is never used, so we can discard it!
    cout << "Please enter a positive integer number: " << endl;
    cin >> x; // Not critical, but I like to put such a cin right after the prompting cout.
    std::string tab{ "\t" }; // Let's initialise more directly!
    do {
        // As there is only one line (now) inside each if/else block, we can leave out the {} ...
        if (x % 2 != 0)
            cout << x << " is odd" << tab << "Subtract 1" << tab << "Half of " << x - 1 << " is " << x / 2;
        else
            cout << x << " is even" << tab << "Subtract 0" << tab << "Half of  " << x << " is " << x / 2;
        // We can put the following two line outside the tests, as they will be the same in both cases:
        x = x / 2; // When x is ODD, this will give the SAME answer as x = (x - 1)/2 (as you noticed in your first cout)
        cout << endl;
    } while (x > 0); // You run forever if you have x >= 0!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that there's no need to subtract 1 before dividing: integer truncation takes care of that.

Comment: @paddy  This is coming in the next edit (BPC - really)! But the OP has actually realized this, if you look at the first `cout` line in his code.

Comment: @paddy See edit! (It was already typed like that - honest, guv!) A minor improvement (depending on taste) would be to change `x = x / 2;` to `x /= 2;` but that's not critical, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I made a few correction to my code and its looking good to go. I wonder why using namespace std isn't a good practice since my current professor in college told us that'ts its better,

Comment: @GGBro Apparently, lots of College Profs teach folks to use it! However, for an informed discussion, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice